# When I upload An Image in CodeIgniter it sends Empty Array

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is the function which inserts data into the database. but it sends an empty file path and does not sends the image to folder and database also. when I use `print_r($this->upload->data()); die;` it shows an Empty array.

```
public function insert_item()
    {

        if($this->form_validation->run('item') == FALSE)
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error" style="color:red">','</div>');
            return $this->add_item();
        }
        else
        {
              $config['upload_path']          = './assets/images/';
              $config['allowed_types']        = 'jpg|png';
              $config['max_size']             = 3000;
              $this->load->library('upload', $config);

              if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('item_file'))
              {
                      $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

              }

              echo "<pre>";
              print_r($this->upload->data($config));die;
        }
        $table = 'category';
        $data['category']  = $this->my_model->select_data($table);
        $this->load->view('admin/items/add_item',$data);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: please initialize it first then check it $this->load->initialize($config);

Comment: add enctype="multipart/form-data" into you form tag.

Comment: where i can write this code?

Comment: Please share your FORM HTML

Comment: @Hetal already initialised with '$this->load->library('upload', $config);'

Answer (score 0):

Please follow:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $error;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Controller code**

```
class Upload extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}

public function index()
{
        $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
}

public function do_upload()
{
        $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']             = 100;
        $config['max_width']            = 1024;
        $config['max_height']           = 768;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
        {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

**Reference URL:** https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: @Kelly Morrison: Please let me know if you are still facing the problem.